# If statement to prevent negative number on realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
enemyHealthBar.html(function(i, val) { 
      return val*1-userDmg; // From 100 subtracts userDmg
});
```

Problem is that if from 100 it subtracts 180 (userDmg) I get -80 result. I need to get 0 instead of -80. How can I achieve this ? I can't get it how to write `if` correctly.

THIS WORKED:

```
   enemyHealthBar.html(function(i, val) { 
        attack = val*1-userDmg; 
       if(attack < 0) {
           return 0;
       } else {
           return val*1-userDmg;
       }
    });
```

Comment: Change the line to: `return val-userDmg > 0 ? val-userDmg : 0;` ...I took out the *1 because val*1 = 1.  The ? and : are equivalent to if-then-else, just shorter.

Comment: Make sure you declare `attack` properly or your variable will leak into the global env.

Comment: @Andy `a || 0` will not work

Comment: @Andy How to declare it properly??

Comment: [Use `const`, `let`, or `var` depending your needs.](https://hackernoon.com/js-var-let-or-const-67e51dbb716f)

Comment: @Andy Don't know how I forgot that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without `if` statement

```
return Math.max(val*1-userDmg, 0)
```

So function can look like:

```
enemyHealthBar.html(function(i, val) { 
  const result = val*1-userDmg;
  return Math.max(result, 0);
});
```

Comment: How to declare `result` variable properly so it won;t leak into the global env. ??

Comment: Fabio has used `const` here.

Answer (score 1):

```
enemyHealthBar.html(function(i, val) {
  let x = val*1-userDmg; // From 100 subtracts userDmg
  if(x <= 0) return 0;
  else return x;
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `else` keyword there fwiw. If it doesn't match the first `return` condition the function will simply return `x`.

Comment: That's very true but as the OP is clearly new to programing I left it in for clarities sake.